# javascript flatten array and remove duplicates with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to flatten an array and remove duplicates in one step using `reduce` and a `Set` but the array is flattened but the duplicates remain.

The related answer speaks to removing duplicates from an array but I would like to flatten and remove duplicates in one step, so I would suggest this might not be a duplicate question.

```js
const wells = [
  [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'well one'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'well two'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'well three'
    },
  ],
  [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'well two'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'well three'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'well four'
    },
  ],
];


const uniqueflattenedWells = wells.reduce(
  (a, b) => Array.from(new Set(a.concat(b))), [],
);

console.log(uniqueflattenedWells)
```

Comment: Objects aren't `===` to each other, so a Set won't de-duplicate

Comment: I edited the question to have it re opened as the suggested answer talks of removing duplicates but I would like to flatten and remove duplicates in one step. so hopefully it will be reopened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) if IDs are ok to determine whether items are duplicated:

```js
const wells = [[{"id":1,"name":"well one"},{"id":2,"name":"well two"},{"id":3,"name":"well three"}],[{"id":2,"name":"well two"},{"id":3,"name":"well three"},{"id":4,"name":"well four"}]];

const uniqueflattenedWells = wells.reduce(
  (a, b) => a.concat(b.filter(o => a.every(x => x.id !== o.id))),
  [],
);

console.log(uniqueflattenedWells)
```

> Note: this method won't dedupe items coming from the same inner Array

Answer (score 0):

Objects are only equal when they are the exact same reference. One way to solve this problem is by using `JSON.stringify` to compare the objects, but note that this is not the fastest method.

```js
const wells = [
  [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'well one'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'well two'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'well three'
    },
  ],
  [{
      id: 2,
      name: 'well two'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'well three'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'well four'
    },
  ],
];


const uniqueflattenedWells = ((set) => wells.reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b), []).filter(obj => {
    const str = JSON.stringify(obj);
    return !set.has(str) && set.add(str);
  })
)(new Set);

console.log(uniqueflattenedWells)
```